# Add Items to Listview automatically after a few seconds

Tags: android, listview

What I wanna do is (similar):

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
    list.add(i);
    listview.setAdapter(...);
    //equivalent sleep method
}
```

The numbers will be added to the Listview dynamically after a few seconds.
What I did so far:

```
int i = 1;
    while (i<20) {
        generate(i);

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(context,list));
                } else if (list.size() == 0) {

                }
            }
        }, 10000);
        i++;
    }
```

But all numbers are showing all at once after a few seconds. In java, I did it by adding the panel to the frame every time. What should I do for Android ?

Answer (score 0):

You are posting all the delayed at the same time with same delayed time, so they will all run at same time.
The easy fix, is to Change the `10000` value, to `10000 * i`. The more correct fix, would be to post only one runnable, and that the runnable itself, posts the next one. That way, you don't have all the runnable in memory at one time.
In addition, it is not clear from your code where you are adding the item to the list. It seems that you are adding it in the loop, not in the runnable, so they are all already in list before first runnable runs. You should move it to the runnable. Also, you should not be creating a new adapter for each iteration. You should change your adapter to have a function called `addItem()`, and it should add the item to its list, and then call `notifyDatasetChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for. You need be careful about scopes of some variables.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context,list);
listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        generate(i);
        if (i < 20) {
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i));
                myCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            } else if (list.size() == 0) {

            }
            i++;
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    }

};
handler.post(runnable);
```